# php wont return json data from db

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli

I've seen a few similar questions and tried the fixes and they are not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm trying to return some data from the database as JSON.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$db         = "signup";
$servername = "localhost";
$username   = "username";
$password   = "password";
$fetch = ("SELECT * FROM bookings"); 
$return_arr = array();

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db); // working 
$query_result = mysqli_query($conn, $fetch);
mysqli_select_db("bookings",$db);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    $return_arr[] = array(
        'TIMESLOT' => $row['TIMESLOT'],
        'USERPIN' => $row['USERPIN'],
        'PLAYERS' => $row['PLAYERS'],
        'ACCEPTED' => $row['ACCEPTED'],
        'EMAIL' =>  $row['EMAIL'],
        'TOTAL BOOKINGS' => $row['TOTALBOOKINGS'],
        'BOOKING ID' => $row['BOOKINGID'],
        'LAST BOOKING' => $row['LASTBOOKING'],
        'DATE' => $row['DATE']
    );
}

$user = json_encode($return_arr);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($return_arr);
echo "</pre>";     

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Now I'm getting this information back from the database:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [TIMESLOT] => 12:00-14:00
            [USERPIN] => 25225649
            [PLAYERS] => 4
            [ACCEPTED] => 0
            [EMAIL] => email@address.com
            [TOTAL BOOKINGS] => 0
            [BOOKING ID] => 1
            [LAST BOOKING] => 0000,00,00
            [DATE] => 0000,00,00
        )
)
```

Comment: From this code it looks like $row_array is empty. Do you want to return json with the column names? If so think it should be $return_arr = array('BOOKINGID' => $row['BOOKINGID'], ....etc

Comment: Tried this with no luck! :(

Comment: You're clobbering `$return_arr` with each `$row` fetched, and you're assigning within the array literal. Many problems here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change the `while` to this:

```php
//...
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db); // working 
$query_result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM bookings");
//...

// Option 1 : Change MYSQL_ASSOC to MYSQLI_ASSOC
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

// Option 2 : Change to mysqli_fetch_assoc
// while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_result)) {      

    // Debug
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($row);
    echo "</pre>";     

    $return_arr[] = array($row['BOOKINGID'],
        $row['USERPIN'],
        $row['TIMESLOT'],
        $row['PLAYERS'],
        $row['ACCEPTED'],
        $row['EMAIL'],
        $row['TOTALBOOKINGS'],
        $row['LASTBOOKING'],
        $row['DATE']
    );
}
```

See that I added brackets to `$return_arr`, otherwise you'll be changing the value of the array and you'll get only the last one.

After that remove the "[0]" from the `$return_arr[0]`. This way you'll have the entire array encoded to json.

Comment: Tried this with no luck! :(

Comment: Have you tried `echoing` the $row variables? Because by seeing your code you have no query at all.

Comment: Try removing the ";" from the query. If you do the query through mysql console or phpmyadmin or anything similar, do you get something? By `echoing` the rows inside the while, do you get something?

Comment: ok I removed the ; from the query ran this in the SQL in phpmyadmin and was returned with the infromation from the database.

ive tried to echo in the while and does not return anything at all. its as if the while is not being exectued.

Comment: Uhmmm... That's weird... If you do a `var_dump` to `return_arr` does it print something?

Comment: vardump returned array(0) { }

Comment: Ok, let's keep trying. If you do a var_dump to $row inside the while does it print something? I'm assuming you are trying all this with the code I suggested.

Comment: ok so, ive updated the code to exactaly what i have in the php file, Ive then added the vardump($row); to the while loop.

I do not get anything for the loop then i get from the last vardump($users) 

string(2) "[]"

Comment: Ok, for what I can see, you are doing the query before the connection and you have to pass the connection to the query, otherwise the query doesn't know where to be executed.

Check this example http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp

Comment: ok so i a followed the example and still get the same results, ive updated the code. i do also get the Conntected echoed out

Comment: I edited my answer with a new code. Try it and see if it works.

According to the examples I've found, the mysqli_query function requires the connection, and the mysqli_fetch_array requieres the result of the mysqli_query.

Comment: Still nothing Eric, I just get the same Result 

string(2) "[]"

This has got me around the bend :( lol

Comment: Hahaha, don't worry, things like this always happen. I edited my answer again to add some debugging. Add what I added under "debug" and show us what it prints and also edit your code to see how it is so far.

Comment: ok, i have some data being returned now but it doesnt make much sense but it is data from the DB i will update it in the code including the new code i have

Comment: Ok, I'm checking your code and I can see that is returning data and it makes sense.

If you check this link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php the mysqli_fetch_array as second parameter expects `MYSQLI_ASSOC`, `MYSQLI_NUM`, or `MYSQLI_BOTH` and you are passing `MYSQL_ASSOC` (without the **i**) so this must be failing.

So you have two choices : change **MYSQL_ASSOC** to **MYSQLI_ASSOC** or change `mysqli_fetch_array()` to `mysqli_fetch_assoc`.

The problem is that it wasn't returning the data as an associative array but as a simple array

I'll edit my answer to show you.

Comment: Ive done it Eric, Im getting the data returned now, it was missing the i from the mysql_assoc.

Thank you soo much for all your help you ledgend!!

Comment: now i just need to parse the data into full callender .js xD ill be back hahaha!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db); // working 

$sql = ""; // your query
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    // Create results array
    $rows[] = array(
                    'BOOKINGID' => $row['BOOKINGID'],
                    'USERPIN' => $row['USERPIN'],
                    // and go on....
                );                              
}

mysqli_close($conn);

echo json_encode($rows[0]);
```

Comment: Tried this with no luck! :(